# Installing SSH2 for PHP to run on a Xampp Apache server on a OSX 10.9.1

Tags: php, macos, apache, xampp, libssh2

I am running Xampp on a Mac with OS X 10.9.1 and I am trying to develop a web page that calls a PHP script through an Ajax call. Xampp is used here for development purposes and it is not intended to form the backend of an online page.

A PHP script needs to connect though ssh to a remote machine, reason for which I
plan to use the ssh2 library. When I try to run the commands:

> $connection = ssh2_connect('my.remote.machine.address', 5432);

I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Project/getdata.php on line 8

and, by calling 'phpinfo()', ssh2 does not seem to be installed. I successfully managed to use ssh2_connect on Windows, Ubuntu and Scientific Linux and after a week I can't seem to figure out what I'm not doing right on a OSX I suspect there could be a problem with broken paths or interaction with the Apache server OSX came with. Here is what I have tried:

I. The MacPorts and PECL method (reference: http://lassebunk.dk/2011/05/26/installing-ssh2-for-php-on-mac-os-x/):

- stuff already on my computer: xcode (from iStore), MacPorts (installer from their site), PHP 5.4.17 and apparently an Apache server that comes with OSX, that I had to stop with:

> sudo apachectl stop

so that the Xampp one worked.

- ran the command:

> sudo port install libssh2

as the libssh2 and openssl libraries are prerequisites to using ssh2_connect in php (reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.requirements.php); openssl appears to be already installed on Xampp's according to phpinfo().

- installed Pear:

> sudo php /usr/lib/php/install-pear-nozlib.phar

- installed Homebrew (otherwise the 'pecl install' commands fail):

> ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go/install)"

- ran:

> brew install autoconf

- now I was finally able to run:

> $ sudo pecl install ssh2-0.12

with "/opt/local" as prefix

- now I got a nice ssh2.so file, which I add to the relevant php.ini:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc

by adding the line:

> extension=/opt/local/lib/php54/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/ssh2.so

- restarted the Xampp Apache Web Server from the GUI that comes with Xampp and still ssh2 was not found.

II. The compile the ssh2.so from the terminal method (reference: zizifu's comment http://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php):

- got the libssh2 archive from http://libssh2.org/ and:

> ./configure
>
> make
>
> make install

- got the latest ssh2 archive from http://pecl.php.net/package/ssh2

> phpize
>
> ./configure --with-ssh2
>
> make
>
> make install

- got a ssh2.so file again, added it to the relevant php.ini, restarted server and it still doesn't work.

Sorry if this has too much detail, hopefully the information I gave can point what I'm doing wrong; I would really appreciate any solution/hint/thing to try to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH2 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/)? It has a number of [advantages over libssh2](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/compare.html), including improved portability and speed. Example:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('pwd');
echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');
?>
```

Comment: I heard about this other option and I will give it a try before doing anything more radical. Other things that I'm considering are switching Xampp for something else or simply do the project on Windows or Ubuntu, although not being able to install a library I'm using in a project on a popular OS would be a bad thing. For now, I'll keep trying to get ssh2 working anyway on the side, as not to leave the question unanswered.