# Unix Commands Remote on windows php

Tags: php, windows, unix, command

I have a Windows PHP Server and i would like to use PHP to connect to a unix Server and run some unix commands on this remote server. Is this feasible? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

You can use PHP `ssh2` commands to do what you're trying to do.

See here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php

Not enough information for me to direct you further.

Comment: I am building an application to monitor the performance of unix servers. thanks for your help

Comment: With the ssh2 functions you should be able to do what you have described in the question title and description.  If this has provided a solution to you, accept it as an answer please.

Comment: Tried setting up SSH2. Keep getting error on libsh2.dll missing. I am trying to use exec commands and PuTTY Plink

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20736170/installing-ssh2-for-php-to-run-on-a-xampp-apache-server-on-a-osx-10-9-1